# In Win32, how can a text file be successfully read into memory?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to get simple file IO working in Win32. So far the writing is working fine, but the reading is not: although it successfully reads the contents, additional "garbage" is appended to the string. The code I have so far is below. The program has `UNICODE` defined.

For writing:

```
DWORD dwTextSize = GetWindowTextLength(hWndTextBox);
WCHAR *lpszText = new WCHAR[dwTextSize];
GetWindowText(hWndTextBox, lpszText, dwTextSize + 1);
hTextFile = CreateFile(lpszTextFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD dwBytesWritten;
WriteFile(hTextFile, lpszText, 2 * dwTextSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);  // x2 for 2 bytes per Unicode character
CloseHandle(hTextFile);
DeleteObject(hTextFile);
```

For this example, `Hello, World!` is saved successfully as `Hello, World!`.

For reading:

```
lpszTextFileName = L"text.txt";        // LPCTSTR Variable
hTextFile = CreateFile(lpszTextFileName, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hTextFile, &dwFileSize);
DWORD dwBytesRead;
WCHAR *lpszText = new WCHAR[dwFileSize / 2];
ReadFile(hTextFile, lpszText, dwFileSize, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
CloseHandle(hTextFile);
```

The string is then used to set the text of an EDIT control:

```
SendMessage(hWndTextBox, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)lpszText);    // SetWindowText() also possible
```

When `Hello, World!` is read back in, it reads back in as `Hello, World!﷽﷽ꮫꮫꮫꮫﻮ` or a visual variation upon this, but basically "garbage"!

I have probably missed something rather obvious, but I cannot see where! Is there a solution to this problem and if so, what is it?

Comment: Null-terminate the string (and make sure to allocate space for that terminator) before sending it to `SendMessage()`. (And in case it wasn't obvious, delete the buffer when you're done with it). Also, `GetWindowText(hWndTextBox, lpszText, dwTextSize + 1)` into a buffer that is allocated on the previous line to be `dwTextSize` probably isn't a wise idea.

Comment: How do I go about null-terminating a string in Win32? Is it simply something like `lpszText[sizeof(lpszText) - 1] = (WCHAR)0; // or '\0'`?

Comment: That will set the 3rd (or 7th, if compiling 64bit) wchar in your string to 0, which is not what you want. `sizeof(pointer-type-var)` is not the same as `sizeof(array-type-var)`. See the post below for how to terminate your string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I started this with a comment, but its getting out of control.

**For Writing**

This:

```
WCHAR *lpszText = new WCHAR[dwTextSize];
```

should be:

```
WCHAR *lpszText = new WCHAR[dwTextSize+1];
```

This:

```
DeleteObject(hTextFile);
```

should not be there **at all.**. Get rid of it.

I'm assuming you `delete [] lpszText;` somewhere when you're done with it. if not, do so.

---

**For Reading**

The second parameter to `GetFileSize()` should not be the same variable as your return value. It is the HIGH 32bit of a 64-bit value for large file sizes. If you know you're file size is smaller than 4gB, you can leave it NULL, so change this:

```
DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hTextFile, &dwFileSize);
```

to this:

```
DWORD dwFileSize = GetFileSize(hTextFile, NULL);
```

You must account for the null terminator of your file buffer, so this:

```
WCHAR *lpszText = new WCHAR[dwFileSize / 2];
```

should be changed to this:

```
WCHAR *lpszText = new WCHAR[dwFileSize / 2 + 1];
lpszText[dwFileSize / 2] = 0;
```

and the rest should work as you're hoping it would. No error checking, which is not good, but I've seen worse. And as before, I'm assuming you `delete [] lpszText;` somewhere when you're done with it. if not, do so.

Comment: Excellent post. It's amazing how 8 lines of code had so many mistakes/issues... I don't know that I would use `lpszText[dwFileSize/2] = 0` personally; I much prefer to `memset` the buffer to all zeroes directly, but that's a style thing.

Comment: @NikBougalis most of it is common for people new to both Windows and C/C++. The only one that made me go "wtf???" was the `DeleteObject()`. Lord knows where *that* came from. And regarding `memset`, its a performance thing. No need to fill memory with a bunch of zeros only to have all-but-one of them overwritten immediately after. Comes from platforms where doing that can get expensive. But whatever works and lets you sleep at night =P

Comment: Yeah, the DeleteObject was peculiar. As for `memset`, I get where you're coming from - I'm a big performance-squeezing geek too, alas it's a requirement we have at my workplace...

Comment: Perfect - many thanks for your help! Yes - the `lpszText` variables were deleted, but I left the code out. I am primarily a .NET developer but decided to try out some Win32 for an experiment/learning exercise, hence the rather large number of mistakes, but I'm gradually getting there!

Comment: @BWHazel you're doing fine. Just tread carefully and *thoroughly* understand an API call (i.e. read its docs) before coding with it. Unlike .NET, C/C++ WIN32 API programming is somewhat unforgiving. In a "That which does not make you stronger kills you." 'sorta way =P

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks! I'm gradually getting used to it - coming from .NET it was indeed quite an eye-opener!